# Facebook Deep 'Like'

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm working on a few e-commerce applications where I'd like users to be able to 'Like' products. It's not always possible to embed the `og:` meta tags on the page that's being 'Liked', either because it's not in our control, or because it's deep in an AJAX application.

I've hit upon the idea of building a proxy for OpenGraph objects. I can point the Like button to the proxy URL, which will serve up all the `og:` metadata describing the product, including a canonical URL.

The trouble is that Facebook follow the canonical URL and parse that for metadata, rather than the proxy page.

Is this a bug in FB's parser, or am I missing something?

I'd appreciate any help or clarification you could offer.

Thanks in advance,

Ross

Comment: check it using this tool http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/

Comment: Thanks @dragonjet.

I have checked it on the linter, which shows the specified `:og` metadata from the proxy, but FB doesn't behave like that in practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the `<link rel="canonical" ...>` tag, maybe try to exclude it from the proxy page's source code when the user-agent of the user is the Facebook user-agent.  This way, user's browsers and search engines see and recognize the canonical url, and the Facebook page crawler doesn't.

Comment: Thanks, Jim.

Our solution will be very similar to what you've suggested there. I think we'll browser sniff on the proxy, supplying metadata to FB's bots (including the proxy page as the `og:url`, but redirecting other user agents to the canonical URL.